# Submit button remains disabled with Phonegap Angularjs on Android 4.0.3 / 4.0.4

Tags: android, angularjs, validation, cordova

I use Angular v1.2.14 and making this form with validation.

```
<form role="form" name="exchangeForm" ng-submit="submitExchange(exchange)" novalidate>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Wat is je naam?" name="name" ng-model="exchange.name" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Wat is je e-mail" name="email" ng-model="exchange.email" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Waar werk je?" name="work" ng-model="exchange.work" required>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-lg" ng-disabled="exchangeForm.$invalid">Prijs claimen</button>
    </form>
```

This is the controller section to save the data:

```
$scope.submitExchange = function(data)
        {
            PhoneGap.ready().then(function()
            {
                var exchange = new Exchange({uuid: $window.device.uuid});
                exchange.name = data.name;
                exchange.email = data.email;
                exchange.work = data.work;
                exchange.$save(function(result)
                {
                    round.state = 3;
                    round.player_name = data.name;
                    round.player_email = data.email;
                    round.player_work = data.work;
                    $route.reload();
                });
            });
        };
```

When i run the Phonegap app on my IPhone, everything works fine. But on Android 4.0.3, the submit button remains disabled even if I've filled in all fields.

Answer (score 0):

In that case it might be easiest to manually remove the button's active state as soon as the validation is completed.

You can do this by calling:

```
$(":submit").parent().removeClass("ui-btn-active");
```